# Serialize object of params to url

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, object

We have input like this

```
const params = {
  id: 1,
  filters: {
    price: {
      min: 101,
      max: 300
    }
  },
  sorters: {
    sortBy: 'price',
    order: 'desc'
  }
}
```

and we want output to look like this `id=1&min=101&max=300&sortBy=price&order=desc`.

Object is nested. If we have object with just 1 level (no object within objects) then we could simply do

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  arr.push(`${key}=${value}`);
}
```

then probably `.join` array with `&`. But here in this case this is not enough. My first though was to just inner this for loops like this:

```
const paramsStringify = (paramsObject) => {
  const arr = []
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(paramsObject)) {
    if(typeof value === 'object') {
      for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(value)) {
        if(typeof value2 === 'object') {
          for (const [key3, value3] of Object.entries(value2)) {
            console.log('3rd lvl', `${key3}: ${value3}`);
            arr.push(`${key3}=${value3}`)
          }
        } else {
          console.log('2nd lvl', `${key2}: ${value2}`);
          arr.push(`${key2}=${value2}`)
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('1st lvl', `${key}: ${value}`);
      arr.push(`${key}=${value}`)
    }
  }
  
  console.log('arr', arr.join('&'))
}
```

[this is working fine](https://codepen.io/BT101/pen/LYGyyWp?editors=0010) but code look awful to me. I nested it three times, if I would have even more nested objects I would need to put another for loop there. But the pattern is same for each level of objects. Can I somehow refactor it so it would work even if I have input with 7 nested objects?

Comment: "Can I somehow refactor it so it would work even if I have input with 7 nested objects?" use recursion :)

Comment: you need a recursive function to achieve that

Comment: Recursive code maybe. Looks like your output does not retain the shape. I think the standard way to pass deep object via URL or formdata is like this `?filters.price.min=101` so may need more work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const params = {
  id: 1,
  filters: {
    price: {
      min: 101,
      max: 300
    }
  },
  sorters: {
    sortBy: 'price',
    order: 'desc'
  }
}

function add(a, o) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') add(a, value); // recursion
    else a.push(`${key}=${value}`); // only if value not-an-object
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(add([], params).join("&"))
```

This is a simple recursive version. You will probably have to tune it if you want to support more complex structures (arrays, duplicate keys, ...)

Comment: @adiga 's version is essentially this code but with safer URL escaping (by using a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object and recursively append key value pairs to it. This will automatically encode values.

```js
const params = {
  id: 1,
  filters: { price: { min: 101, max: 300 } },
  sorters: { sortBy: "price", order: "desc" }
}

function getParam(o, searchParam = new URLSearchParams) {
  Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v !== null && typeof v === 'object')
      getParam(v, searchParam)
    else
      searchParam.append(k, v)
  })
  
  return searchParam
}

const searchParam = getParam(params);

console.log(
  searchParam.toString()
)
```

Comment: How does one get back the params dictionary from just the string ```"id=1&min=101&max=300&sortBy=price&order=desc"```?

Comment: @Kevin `Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams("id=1&min=101&max=300"))`

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to "flatten" and only take the innermost elements. Would it be possible to preserve the dictionary hierarchy? For example using the same ```params``` in your post and doing ```Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(getParam(params).toString()))``` should return the same dictionary ```params```

Comment: @Kevin the query string created is a flattened key value pairs. The earlier structure is not maintained. If you create a custom query string like `filters.price.min=101&sorters.sortBy=price`, you can convert it back with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object adheres to your example, use a URLSearchParams object and avoid recursion using a regex

```js
const params = {
  id: 1,
  filters: {
    price: {
      min: 101,
      max: 300
    }
  },
  sorters: {
    sortBy: 'price',
    order: 'desc'
  }
}

const js = JSON.stringify(params);
const re = /"(\w+)":[^\{]?"?(\w+)"?/g
const usp = new URLSearchParams();
js.match(re).forEach(str => {
  const [key,val] = str.split(":");
  usp.set(key.replace(/"/g,""),val.replace(/"/g,""))
})
console.log(usp.toString())
```

Comment: The regex will mangle JSON with escapes in them. @adiga 's answer is, in that sense, much more solid.

Comment: @tucuxi - sure. It was not written when I was writing mine (but posted before I posted) - I assume a few things

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a recursive function if you don't want to program the same logic for each nested object. See https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/ for more information about recursive functions.