# Deserialize querystring

Tags: javascript

How do I (de)serialize a nested dictionary by using a querystring? I have looked at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531914/serialize-object-of-params-to-url/62532147) on how to serialize nested objects but I cannot find a convenient way of preserving the original dictionary hierarchy/layout when deserialization.

Suppose I have the following input:

```
const params = {
  id: 1,
  filters: {
    price: {
      min: 101,
      max: 300
    }
  },
  sorters: {
    sortBy: 'price',
    order: 'desc'
  }
}
```

How do I convert this back and forth using a querystring?

I am able to convert it to a querystring by using jquery `$.param`, but when I try to convert it back to the original `params` it's incorrect:

```
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams($.param(params)))
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "filters[price][min]": "101",
  "filters[price][max]": "300",
  "sorters[sortBy]": "price",
  "sorters[order]": "desc"
}
```

Comment: URLSearchParams is meant for url-encoded strings, not JSON. The two formats are completely unrelated. Furthermore you should not encode object-graphs in URIs because many UAs have length-limits on URIs - I find a total length of 1024 characters (including URI scheme, host name and path) is reliable.

Comment: I think you have an X/Y Problem. Please tell us **why** you want to flatten an object to a querystring? If you want to move data around then use a POST request body. Note that GET requests are not meant for effecting changes to saved data - but GET requests *can* have a body if you’re using a graph to represents a query, e.g. GraphQL or when you send (sandboxed) executable code to a big-data aggregation system.

Comment: I want to pass the JSON object ```params``` to the page by using a GET request and the only way I can think of doing this is by specifying ```params``` in the URL. I can also encode the stringified JSON object as a single field in the querystring, but I am not sure if this the best way of doing it.

Comment: In that case I assume you control the page/endpoint that you're sending the data to? In that case why can't use you a `GET` request body instead? Or `POST` it if necessary?

Comment: using the ```GET``` request body would be the most suitable, but I want to send the URL with some querystring (extra data) to someone and I cannot specify the ```GET``` request body on their behalf.

Comment: The whole point is to use a shareable link, maybe I should have been more specific about that point.

Comment: I think you should just define much shorter querystring names on your HTTP endpoint, like. `minPrice`, `maxPrice`, `sortBy`, and so on - using your example data it would be `/your/website?minPrice=101&maxPrice=300&orderBy=price&dir=desc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233981/discussion-between-kevin-and-dai).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in chat - it seems you want to be able to use the same object-graph representation of query-criteria on both the client and the server (which is reasonable) - the good news is that because your object-graph has a consistent design you can write a straightforward function that serializes the graph to a more succinct URI querystring representation *without* redundant parameter name prefixes or wasted brace/colon/quote space...

To summarize:

- The only *variadic* part of your `params` object is the `filters:` sub-object. The `id` and `sorters` parts have a *fixed* layout - which means having a `filters[]` part is unnecessary.

So this:

```
const params = {
  id: 1,
  filters: {
    price: {
      min: 101,
      max: 300
    }
  },
  sorters: {
    sortBy: 'price',
    order: 'desc'
  }
}
```

can be serialized to this:

```
id=1&price_min=101&price_max=300&sortBy=price&dir=desc
```

---

Here's some logic that would deserialize such a querystring back into the `params` object you had originally:

```
const queryObject = {
    id: null,
    filter: {},
    sorters: {}
};

const qs = new URLSearchParams( "id=1&price_min=101&price_max=300&sortBy=price&dir=desc" );

for(const [key, value] of qs) {
    if( key === 'id' ) queryObject.id = value;
    else if( key === 'sortBy' ) queryObject.sorters.sortBy = value;
    else if( key === 'dir' ) queryObject.sorters.order = value;
    else {
        if( key.endsWith("_min") || key.endsWith("_max") ) {
            const name = key.substring(0, key.indexof("_"));
            if( !name in queryObject.filters ) {
                queryObject.filters[name] = {};
            }
            if( key.endsWith("_min") ) {
                queryObject.filters[name].min = value;
            } else {
                queryObject.filters[name].max = value;
            }
        }
        else {
            queryObject.filters[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Serializing `params` to `URLSearchParams` is also straightforward:

```
const qs = new URLSearchParams();
if( 'id' in params ) qs.set('id', params['id']);
if( 'sortBy' in params.sorters ) qs.set('sortBy', params.sorters.sortBy);
if( 'order' in params.sorters ) qs.set('dir', params.sorters.order);

for( const key of params.filters ) {
    if( typeof(params.filters[key] === 'object') {
        qs.set(key + '_min') = params.filters[key].min;
        qs.set(key + '_max') = params.filters[key].max;
    }
    else {
        qs.set(key) = params.filters[key];
    }
}
```